# "virtualbox is not installed" : Error while uninstalling virtual box on Mac

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I have installed `vagrant` and `virtualbox` on my Mac using `brew cask`. I want to uninstall virtual box. I get the following error when I run the `brew cask uninstall virtualbox`

```
Error: virtualbox is not installed
```

I can clearly see that virtualbox is installed on my machine and it appears in launcher section. I also see virtualbox, when I run the following command.

```
$brew cask list
adium          adobe-reader   consul         google-chrome  iterm2     java6      osxfuse    vagrant    virtualbox     xquartz
```

Am I missing something here which prevents me to uninstall virtualbox. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `brew cask uninstall --force virtualbox`

Comment: that didnn't help I get the following error:`brew cask uninstall --force virtualbox
==> Running uninstall process for virtualbox; your password may be necessary
==> sudo: /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/virtualbox/4.3.20-96996/VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool: command not found
Error: Command failed to execute!

==> Failed command:
["/usr/bin/sudo", "-E", "--", "#<Pathname:/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/virtualbox/4.3.20-96996/VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool>", "--unattended"]

==> Output of failed command:


==> Exit status of failed command:
#<Process::Status: pid 15933 exit 1>`

Comment: @Rakesh, you should install virtualbox and then uninstall it, it will fix your problem

Comment: I have already tried it, but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gaussblurinc stated, installing and and uninstalling works.

```
brew cask install virtualbox
```

wait for it to complete....

```
brew cask uninstall virtualbox
```

This same solutions works for virtualbox-extension-pack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug #2580](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/2580) -> [#14058](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/14058)  in `brew cask list`. You can hard remove all existing casks with:

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/virtualbox
```

or

```
brew cask zap virtualbox
```

You can then reinstall.

Comment: This nukes everything... hardly as solution.

Comment: But the whole point of cask is that it is easy to re-install. If you can't uninstall and re-install one app, then uninstalling everything and reinstalling everything is not much slower.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative to force the uninstallation.

brew uninstall --cask  virtualbox --force

Regards!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please describe the advantages of this solution and how they are achieved, you can also state the date when this became possible. "better" is a judgement, StackOverflow has the voting concept for that. "updated" only makes sense with reference to a date. Both could be misread as "my solution is the best, honest".